# update a document using mongodb by the Id of the document

Tags: mongodb

how to update a document using mongodb by the Id of the document, this is what I tried to do:
I am retrieving the document with the given id from the db,
then construct a new user with the information provided by the user
and update the userinformation to the db.

```
 var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {
      console.log(args);
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("UserApp");
      //retrieve the document with the given id from the db
      let user = await dbo
        .collection("users")
        .findOne({ _id: ObjectId(args.id) }, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
        });

      const myquery = { name: user.name };

      // construct a new user with the information provided by the user
      const newuser = new User({
        name: args.name,
        title: args.title,
        email: args.email,
      });
      // update the userinformation to the db
      dbo.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newuser, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        db.close();
      });
    });
```

Comment: what happened then? did it not save or find?

Comment: also what is ```args```?

Comment: Are you intending to replace all of the fields on the existing document, or keep the old fields while setting the 3 new values?